# Semantic UI tabs and AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use Semantic-UI's tab with angular, but I'm currently facing a problem that I can't fix. Let me state that I'm quite new to both semantic and angular first.
Here's the semantic tab's structure I started with:

```
<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui centered secondary menu">
    <a class="red item active" data-tab="first">First</a>
    <a class="red item" data-tab="second">Second</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ui active tab segment" data-tab="first">First</div>
  <div class="ui tab segment" data-tab="secondo">Second</div>
</div>
```

The tab's behaviour is triggered by the semantic javascript:

```
<script>
  $('.menu .item').tab();
</script>
```

So far so good, everything works just as it's supposed to. Now my problem kicks in: the page's angular controller provides an object that holds (potentially) several different objects inside; for the sake of simplicity lets assume these objects to be 2. The parent object (the one actually served by the controller) has this structure:

```
{
    "1" : {
        "category": "car",
        "type" : [
            {name: "car1"},
            {name: "car2"}
        ]
    },
    "2": {
        "category": "bike",
        "type" : [
            {name: "bike1"}
        ]
    }
}
```

At this point my goal is to use the above tab structure to show the object content, with the types as content and the categories as tab headers. After several attempts this is what I've got:

```
<div class="ui centered secondary menu">
  <a ng-repeat="object in carsObj" class="red item" data-tab="{{object.category}}" ng-class="{active: $index == 0}">{{object.category}}</a>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="object in carsObj" class="ui tab segment" data-tab="{{object.category}}" ng-class="{active: $index == 0}">
  <div class="ui relaxed divided list">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="type in object.types">
      <div class="content">
        <a class="header">{{type.name}}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

assuming carsObj to be the controller's object. I'm using `ng-repeat` to build as many tabs as the objects within carsObj (so I need to iterate twice, one for item menu and one for the actual tab segment). As `data-tab` I'm using the `category` of the inner object in both iteration and, last but not least, I'm giving the `active` class to the first element (again both sides) through `ng-class`. Here's I'm stack, no matter what, the tab doesn't work. It actually shows itself properly, the first tab (the active one) is ok while the second one is not responding, I can see the tab item, but clicking it gets me nowhere, as if the semantic `.tab()` wasn't there. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question but it works for me now.

The thing is that you have to initiate your tabs again using,

```
$('.menu .item')
  .tab();
```

For example, after you using angularJS ngRepeat create a tab series, you need to add a trigger to initiate the tabs using above code. Like,

```
$("#triggerButton").click(function(){
    $('.menu .item')
      .tab();
})
```

After this, your tabs will function.